# Why Cartesian joins could be prohibitively expensive and are disabled by default with Or Condition not for and condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to test or condition in pyspark. So I worte following program

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 2.0), (2, "b", 3.0), (3, "c", 3.0),(4, "h", 5.0)],
    ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "f", -1.0), (2, "p", 0.0),(5, "g", -9.0),(7, "h", -2.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))
df = df1.join(df2, (df1.x1 == df2.x1) | (df1.x2 == df2.x2))
df.show()
```

It's giving error message `AnalysisException: u'Cartesian joins could be prohibitively expensive and are disabled by default. To explicitly enable them, please set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true;'`

But if I replace | by & then same query is running without any error message. Can you please suggest me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update your spark version, the code works on my machine without any warnings or errors with python 2.7 and 3.6 and spark version 2.2.0.

Comment: Hi Srinivas,My question is why or operator is converting to Cartesian join while & operator is not showing Cartesian join for the same query.I saw the link you shared before posting my question but I don't think that post is  able to answer my query.

Comment: From the linked answer what I understood was that some join statements invoke cross join internally, that is essentially what is happening when you are using the "or" condition with the inner join that you are performing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting how this join statement invoke cross join internally!!!  OK Forget about cross join. Are you able to suggest me what modification I need to do in "or" query to get same output without any error?

Comment: If you think about it, an inner join is just a Cartesian join with equality conditions applied, so an inner join can be implemented by invoking a cross join internally. As to what change you have to make, give me a little time to answer that.

Comment: OK.Take your time

Comment: Actually your exact code works on my machine, with both python2.7 and python3.6. I think you should update your spark version.

Comment: I have spark version 2.0.2.Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: Spark version 2.2.0